# Github API to search folder inside a repository

Tags: github-api

Is there any GitHub API availble to search a specific folder in a repository.
I searched for this on official site but I could not find any.

Comment: I believe you're looking for the `trees` endpoint. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/trees?apiVersion=2022-11-28

Comment: The payload you get from the `commits` endpoint will include the url to the root tree and each trees payload includes the urls to the children files and trees.

Comment: thanks i was able to dig till all the level unless i found required target